# How to run the Reactjs Web Application in localhost:3000 in windows

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cmd, redux

I'm a new React Developer, and I'm having a problem in running it to my chrome. I already did the `npm install` in cmd, and then I `npm start` by its  not starting because of error  in cmd. And my OS is Windows 10.

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: have you used create-react-app or if not what is the command that is run when you run npm start, because I see rm command being executed which is not recognised by windows machine

Comment: share your start script. you're probably running a script written for linux

Comment: We need to see what your package.json looks like, and we need to know more about your developer environment like if you're using webpack or gulp to see if their are any errors. For a new React developer, I believe create-react-app makes it easier to start coding. Here is the link if you don't know about it already: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/installation.html

Comment: this is in my package.json

"scripts": {
    "start": "rm -rf __globals__ && cp -fR ../../globals __globals__ && eslint --max-warnings 1 . && node scripts/start.js",
..etc..

Comment: what should I put the in scripts?

Comment: As simple as it is, rm command and cp commands are not windows commands and hence this fails for you, you can either run a separate script on windows that does the same thing or replace the globals folder from within the configuration

Comment: thanks . do you have suggestion what to put in package.json in scripts ?

Comment: have you installed `webpack-dev-server` ?

Comment: if not  install using `npm i webpack-dev-server` then add this inside scripts inpackage.json file `start:webpack-dev-server` this will start your application

Comment: Assuming you are using `webpack`

Comment: Just use creat-react-app as pointed by other comments. It's from far easier than setting up every thing by hand.

Answer (score 0):

in your `package.json` file the script define `rm` command witch is not available in windows that's why you are getting error

insted of `rm` change it to  `del`

and if there is any UNIX specific command then change it to windows equivalent